Set supply After Minting?
so essentially I followed solana examples and I sucessfully minted a token with
'use anchor_spl::{
    metadata::{
        create_metadata_accounts_v3, mpl_token_metadata::types::DataV2,
        CreateMetadataAccountsV3, Metadata,
    },
    token::{Mint, Token},
};'

I've seen the transaction already etc.
But now I need to define the amount of tokens to mint, is there a default already or I need to call the mint units function?
Aprreciated if you got some better docs that I can read!
Thanks!
My test btw:
  it('Create an SPL Token!', async () => {
// Generate new keypair to use as address for mint account.

const mintKeypair = new Keypair();

// SPL Token default = 9 decimals
const transactionSignature = await program.methods
  .createTokenMint(9, metadata.name, metadata.symbol, metadata.uri)
  .accounts({
    payer: payer.publicKey,
    mintAccount: mintKeypair.publicKey,
  })
  .signers([mintKeypair])
  .rpc();

console.log('Success!');
console.log(`   Mint Address: ${payer.publicKey}`);
console.log(`   Transaction Signature: ${transactionSignature}`);

});

Put simply: you need to mint tokens to increase the supply. You can mint as many as you want, and then revoke any future minting

I've not seen someone set the supply after creating the token mint before. Using Metaplex CPI Instruction builders, you can set the supply in the print_supply() as a limited supply. .print_supply(mpl_token_metadata::types::PrintSupply::Limited(args.supply))
    #[access_control(ctx.accounts.validate())]
    pub fn create(ctx: Context<CreateToken>, args: CreateTokenArgs) -> Result<()> {
        CreateV1CpiBuilder::new(&ctx.accounts.metadata_program)
            .metadata(&ctx.accounts.metadata_account)
            .mint(&ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(), true)
            .authority(&ctx.accounts.payer)
            .payer(&ctx.accounts.payer)
            .update_authority(&ctx.accounts.payer, true)
            .system_program(&ctx.accounts.system_program)
            .sysvar_instructions(&ctx.accounts.sysvar_instruction.to_account_info())
            .spl_token_program(Some(&ctx.accounts.token_program))
            .token_standard(mpl_token_metadata::types::TokenStandard::Fungible)
            .seller_fee_basis_points(0) //
            .print_supply(mpl_token_metadata::types::PrintSupply::Limited(args.supply))
            .name(args.name)
            .symbol(args.symbol.unwrap_or_default())
            .uri(args.uri)
            .decimals(args.decimals)
            .invoke()?;

        Ok(())
    }

Check out the full example in this repo
